# Python Fanspeed Interpolation - Return wrong value

Tags: python, interpolation

At the moment i'm working with interpolation in python. You have a fan table with temperature and rpm. The input is a temperature and the output the new processed rpm value. I don't get the right value. Can you help me?

```
TABLE = [
(0, 0),
(20, 10),
(50, 30),
(80, 90),
(100, 100)]

def interPolation(table, input):
    if input < table[0][0]:
        return table[0][1]
    elif input > table[-1][0]:
        return table[-1][1]
    else:
        for n, _ in enumerate(table):
            if table[n][0] <= input <= table[n + 1][0]:
                return (table[n + 1][0] - table[n][0]) / (table[n + 1][1] - table[n][1]) * input + table[n][1]

print interPolation(TABLE, 66)
```

Comment: What value are you expecting, and what are you getting instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all i would suggest **sorting** the table just in case. The sorting would be done inside the function.

If you do not sort it and it is provided in let's say *reverse* or *arbitrary* order (for whatever reason) your `if` and `elif` statements that check to make sure you are in range would be **wrong**. Alternatively, you could use the `min()` and `max()` functions.

Finally, for the `else` part which is where the interpolation happens, i would use a `while` statement to search for the closest recorded value (again a sorted table is crucial here) and do the calculation like so:

```
def interPolation(table, user_value):
    table = sorted(table, key=lambda x: x[0])
    if user_value < table[0][0]:
        return table[0][1]
    elif user_value > table[-1][0]:
        return table[-1][1]
    else:
        i = 0
        while user_value >= table[i][0]:
            i += 1
        return table[i-1][1] + (user_value - table[i-1][0]) * (table[i][1] - table[i-1][1]) / (table[i][0] - table[i-1][0])

table_inp = [(0, 0), (20, 10), (50, 30), (80, 90), (100, 100)]

print(interPolation(table_inp, 66))  # returns 62.0
```

As you might have noticed, i changed your variable names. A general rule is to use lowercase letters (`TABLE` changed to `table`) and avoid using names bound to python functions (`input()` changed to `user_value`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of interpolation you are doing but it seems you are trying to do linear interpolation, in that case you are applying a wrong formula here, 1st of all your formula is dimension wise incorrect. I have tried to correct that part, check it gives you the correct ans

```
data = [
(0, 0),
(20, 10),
(50, 30),
(80, 90),
(100, 100)]

def interPolation(table, temp):
    if temp < table[0][0]:
        return table[0][1]
    elif temp > table[-1][0]:
        return table[-1][1]
    else:
        for n, _ in enumerate(table):
            if table[n][0] <= temp <= table[n + 1][0]:
                return (table[n + 1][1] - table[n][1]) / (table[n + 1][0] - table[n][0]) * (temp-table[n][0]) + table[n][1]

print interPolation(data, 66)
```

Gives ans 62

Comment: Yes, it's linear interpolation. Your code looks better but I don't get the right value. e.g. Input=10, Output=0

Comment: No for input 10 it gives me output 5,  if you are using python 2 then try importing division from `__future__` .